# Insert new key value pair inside and array of objects, but value is created by axios.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

So I've been working on a scraper. Everything was well until I've tried scraping data for individual link.

Now to explain: I've got a scraper, which scrapes me data about apartments. Now first url is page where the articles are located(approx. 29-30 should be fetched). Now on that page I don't have information about square meters, so I need to run another scraper for each link that is scraped, and scrape square meters from there.

Here is the code that I have:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = `https://www.olx.ba/pretraga?vrsta=samoprodaja&kategorija=23&sort_order=desc&kanton=9&sacijenom=sacijenom&stranica=2`;
axios.get(url).then((response) => {
  const articles = [];
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

  $('div[id="rezultatipretrage"] > div')
    .not('div[class="listitem artikal obicniArtikal  i index"]')
    .not('div[class="obicniArtikal"]')
    .each((index, element) => {
      $('span[class="prekrizenacijena"]').remove();
      const getLink = $(element).find('div[class="naslov"] > a').attr('href');
      const getDescription = $(element)
        .find('div[class="naslov"] > a > p')
        .text();
      const getPrice = $(element)
        .find('div[class="datum"] > span')
        .text()
        .replace(/\.| ?KM$/g, '')
        .replace(' ', '');
      const getPicture = $(element)
        .find('div[class="slika"] > img')
        .attr('src');

      articles[index] = {
        id: getLink.substring(27, 35),
        link: getLink,
        description: getDescription,
        price: getPrice,
        picture: getPicture,
      };
    });

  articles.map((item, index) => {
    axios.get(item.link).then((response) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
      const sqa = $('div[class="df2  "]').first().text();
    });
  });

  console.log(articles);
});
```

Now the first part of the code likes as it should, I've been struggling with this second part.

Now I'm mapping over `articles` because there, for each link, I need to load it into `axios` function and get the data about square meters.

So my desired output would be updated articles: with it's old objects and key values inside it but with key sqm and value of scraped sqaure meters.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add the information about the square meters to the current `article`/`item`, something like:

```
const articlePromises = Promise.all(articles.map((item) => {
            return axios.get(item.link).then((response) => {
                const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
                const sqa = $('div[class="df2  "]').first().text();
                item.sqm = sqa;
            });
        }));

articlePromises.then(() => {
    console.log(articles);    
});
```

Note that you need to wait for all mapped promises to resolve, before you log the resulting articles.
Also note that using `async/await` you could rewrite your code to be a bit cleaner, see https://javascript.info/async-await.